# LIKE operator and % wildcard when string contains underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that stores codes. Depending on the nomenclature, some begin with **'DB_'** and others with **'DBL_'**. I need a way to filter the ones that start with **'DB_'**, since when I try to do it, it returns all the results.

```
CREATE TABLE CODES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name Varchar(20));

INSERT INTO CODES VALUES(1,'DBL_85_RC001');
INSERT INTO CODES VALUES(2,'DBL_85_RC002');
INSERT INTO CODES VALUES(3,'DBL_85_RC003');
INSERT INTO CODES VALUES(4,'DB_20_SE_RC010');
INSERT INTO CODES VALUES(5,'DB_20_SE_RC011');

SELECT * FROM CODES where Name like 'DB_%';
```

The result that returns:

```
1|DBL_85_RC001
2|DBL_85_RC002
3|DBL_85_RC003
4|DB_20_SE_RC010
5|DB_20_SE_RC011
```

Expected result:

```
4|DB_20_SE_RC010
5|DB_20_SE_RC011
```

Comment: Side note, though you've posted both DDL and DML (great!!) make sure it's valid. The above suffers truncation issues and thus doesn't work,

Comment: @Larnu What is the truncation error? I ran the code in a [SQLite v3.20.1 compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php) and it gave no errors.

Comment: @Larnu Ohhh, I already saw it. Length of the varchar. Well, it seems strange to me that that compiler did not detect it! I already changed the length from 10 to 20.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c457aae8470a7704b75bf5701889426) SQLite <> SQL Server, TomuRain ; you've tagged SQL Server here *not* SQLite. Are you saying you're actually using SQLite?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I thought they use the same engine. My mistake. No, i'm using SQL Server. But to test the example I used SQLite.

Comment: So, again, are you saying you are actually using SQLite..?

Comment: @Larnu No, i'm not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is a wildcard for a single character in a `LIKE` expression. Thus  both `'DB_'` and `'DBL'` are `LIKE 'DB_'`. If you want a literal underscore you need to put it in brackets (`[]`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CODES
WHERE [Name] LIKE 'DB[_]%';
```

Answer (score 2):

The underscore is a wildcard in SQL Server.  You can escape it:

```
where name like 'DB$_%' escape '$'
```

You could also use `left()`:

```
where left(name, 3) = 'DB_'
```

However, this is not index- and optimizer friendly.

Comment: `SELECT 1 WHERE 'DB_FOO' LIKE 'DB\_%'` doesn't return anything without an explicit `ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: Was about to comment the same as @MartinSmith . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23141b7c0b6c18caa3c244b3bc5e800b) It is also [documentated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that `\ ` is not the default escape character: "*escape_character* is a character expression **that has no default** and must evaluate to only one character."